# Pass a variable ( a flag ) from urls.py to views.py in django

Tags: django, redirect, django-views, django-urls

I currently have a 'blog' app which will display blogposts by different users depending on the username. This is what my urls.py looks like.

```
urlpatterns = patterns('blog.views',
              url(r'^(?P<blog_author>[^/]+)/$', 'entries',  name='blog'),
              url(r'^(?P<blog_author>[^/]+)/(?P<entry_slug>[^/]+)/$', 'blog_entry', name='blog_entry'),
          )
```

So, `blog/authorname/` would list out all the blogpost entries by that particular author and `blog/authorname/foo-post/` will render a particular blog post. What I am trying to do is to permanently redirect blogposts of alumni members to `blog/alumni/authorname` and `blog/alumni/authorname/foo-post/` respectively. I have added a field in my user model which will indicate whether a user is an alumni or not.

The views function is basically the same for both normal users and alumni. Here is what I have been trying to do so far: Inside the `entries` view function, I added some lines that would do the checking of alumni member. If a certain blog author is an alumni, will `HttpResponsePermanentRedirect` to `blogs/alumni/alumni_author/` and since the rendering part is the same, call the same `entries` view function. So basically, my `entries` function is trying to do **checking member types**, **rendering view for both normal and alumni members**.

Comment: It looks to me that you just have to set up a url with `url(r'^alumni/(?P<blog_author>[^/]+)/$', 'entries',  name='blog_alumni'),` and of course not do the redirect then.

Answer (score 7):

You can send a flag from the urlconf to the view by using the optional third parameter:

```
url(r'^alumni/(?P<blog_author>[^/]+)/$', 'entries', {'alumni': True}, name='blog'),
```

Comment: Pardon my noob-ness. How will I access that flag from my view function?

Comment: In the normal way - it's passed in as a parameter to the function, just like `blog_author`.